# Convert list of lists to dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested, type-conversion

I got a nested list, named `mylist` which has length 4.

Each element of this list is an experiment: `exp1.1`, `exp1.2`, `exp2.1` and `exp2.2`.

Each experiment contains observations of length (in days) of four plant growth stages: `EM-V6` `V6-R0` `R0-R4` and `R4-R9`.

Each growth stage is organized as a data frame with `year` and `mean`.

Here is the complete data:

```
mylist=structure(list(exp1.1 = structure(list(`EM-V6` = structure(list(
    year = 2011:2100, mean = c(34, 34, 32, 28, 25, 32, 32, 28, 
    27, 30, 32, 31, 33, 28, 26, 31, 33, 27, 34, 26, 28, 27, 27, 
    30, 29, 31, 34, 30, 26, 31, 33, 33, 27, 30, 28, 32, 31, 29, 
    32, 31, 25, 28, 28, 26, 32, 29, 26, 31, 28, 29, 30, 25, 27, 
    32, 27, 28, 28, 30, 24, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 26, 28, 26, 26, 
    28, 31, 30, 27, 26, 28, 25, 24, 24, 30, 27, 26, 26, 27, 26, 
    26, 24, 26, 28, 25, 30, 26)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `V6-R0` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(30, 33, 33, 32, 29, 30, 32, 31, 32, 30, 33, 30, 
    32, 33, 33, 32, 29, 31, 32, 28, 31, 29, 36, 29, 30, 30, 33, 
    31, 33, 30, 34, 32, 29, 31, 28, 30, 30, 29, 34, 31, 32, 31, 
    30, 28, 32, 29, 29, 32, 29, 28, 29, 29, 32, 31, 27, 32, 29, 
    31, 29, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 32, 29, 29, 
    30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 30, 28, 30, 30, 
    29, 29, 29)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R0-R4` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(31, 32, 32, 33, 32, 32, 33, 31, 34, 32, 33, 33, 
    32, 31, 33, 31, 32, 32, 32, 30, 32, 31, 34, 30, 31, 32, 34, 
    33, 34, 32, 36, 33, 32, 32, 31, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
    31, 30, 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 31, 31, 32, 30, 32, 29, 
    32, 31, 30, 32, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 31, 32, 31, 31, 
    30, 30, 30, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 
    31, 30, 30)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R4-R9` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(27, 29, 28, 28, 27, 30, 29, 27, 30, 26, 30, 28, 
    29, 28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 25, 26, 26, 25, 27, 27, 27, 28, 30, 
    28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 29, 28, 26, 26, 28, 28, 30, 28, 27, 25, 
    26, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 24, 27, 25, 
    28, 26, 24, 27, 26, 27, 25, 26, 26, 24, 26, 25, 26, 24, 25, 
    25, 26, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 
    26, 25, 24)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("EM-V6", "V6-R0", "R0-R4", 
"R4-R9")), exp1.2 = structure(list(`EM-V6` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(34, 34, 32, 28, 25, 32, 32, 28, 27, 30, 32, 31, 
    33, 28, 26, 31, 33, 27, 34, 26, 28, 27, 27, 30, 29, 31, 34, 
    30, 26, 31, 33, 33, 27, 30, 28, 32, 31, 29, 32, 31, 25, 28, 
    28, 26, 32, 29, 26, 31, 28, 29, 30, 25, 27, 32, 27, 28, 28, 
    30, 24, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 26, 28, 26, 26, 28, 31, 30, 27, 
    26, 28, 25, 24, 24, 30, 27, 26, 26, 27, 26, 26, 24, 26, 28, 
    25, 30, 26)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `V6-R0` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(30, 33, 33, 32, 29, 30, 32, 31, 32, 30, 33, 30, 
    32, 33, 33, 32, 29, 31, 32, 28, 31, 29, 36, 29, 30, 30, 33, 
    31, 33, 30, 34, 32, 29, 31, 28, 30, 30, 29, 34, 31, 32, 31, 
    30, 28, 32, 29, 29, 32, 29, 28, 29, 29, 32, 31, 27, 32, 29, 
    31, 29, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 32, 29, 29, 
    30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 30, 28, 30, 30, 
    29, 29, 29)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R0-R4` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(31, 32, 32, 33, 32, 32, 33, 31, 34, 32, 33, 33, 
    32, 31, 33, 31, 32, 32, 32, 30, 32, 31, 34, 30, 31, 32, 34, 
    33, 34, 32, 36, 33, 32, 32, 31, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
    31, 30, 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 31, 31, 32, 30, 32, 29, 
    32, 31, 30, 32, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 31, 32, 31, 31, 
    30, 30, 30, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 
    31, 30, 30)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R4-R9` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(27, 29, 28, 28, 27, 30, 29, 27, 30, 26, 30, 28, 
    29, 28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 25, 26, 26, 25, 27, 27, 27, 28, 30, 
    28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 29, 28, 26, 26, 28, 28, 30, 28, 27, 25, 
    26, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 24, 27, 25, 
    28, 26, 24, 27, 26, 27, 25, 26, 26, 24, 26, 25, 26, 24, 25, 
    25, 26, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 
    26, 25, 24)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("EM-V6", "V6-R0", "R0-R4", 
"R4-R9")), exp2.1 = structure(list(`EM-V6` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(34, 34, 32, 28, 25, 32, 32, 28, 27, 30, 32, 31, 
    33, 28, 26, 31, 33, 27, 34, 26, 28, 27, 27, 30, 29, 31, 34, 
    30, 26, 31, 33, 33, 27, 30, 28, 32, 31, 29, 32, 31, 25, 28, 
    28, 26, 32, 29, 26, 31, 28, 29, 30, 25, 27, 32, 27, 28, 28, 
    30, 24, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 26, 28, 26, 26, 28, 31, 30, 27, 
    26, 28, 25, 24, 24, 30, 27, 26, 26, 27, 26, 26, 24, 26, 28, 
    25, 30, 26)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `V6-R0` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(30, 33, 33, 32, 29, 30, 32, 31, 32, 30, 33, 30, 
    32, 33, 33, 32, 29, 31, 32, 28, 31, 29, 36, 29, 30, 30, 33, 
    31, 33, 30, 34, 32, 29, 31, 28, 30, 30, 29, 34, 31, 32, 31, 
    30, 28, 32, 29, 29, 32, 29, 28, 29, 29, 32, 31, 27, 32, 29, 
    31, 29, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 32, 29, 29, 
    30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 30, 28, 30, 30, 
    29, 29, 29)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R0-R4` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(31, 32, 32, 33, 32, 32, 33, 31, 34, 32, 33, 33, 
    32, 31, 33, 31, 32, 32, 32, 30, 32, 31, 34, 30, 31, 32, 34, 
    33, 34, 32, 36, 33, 32, 32, 31, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
    31, 30, 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 31, 31, 32, 30, 32, 29, 
    32, 31, 30, 32, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 31, 32, 31, 31, 
    30, 30, 30, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 
    31, 30, 30)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R4-R9` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(27, 29, 28, 28, 27, 30, 29, 27, 30, 26, 30, 28, 
    29, 28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 25, 26, 26, 25, 27, 27, 27, 28, 30, 
    28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 29, 28, 26, 26, 28, 28, 30, 28, 27, 25, 
    26, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 24, 27, 25, 
    28, 26, 24, 27, 26, 27, 25, 26, 26, 24, 26, 25, 26, 24, 25, 
    25, 26, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 
    26, 25, 24)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("EM-V6", "V6-R0", "R0-R4", 
"R4-R9")), exp2.2 = structure(list(`EM-V6` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(34, 34, 32, 28, 25, 32, 32, 28, 27, 30, 32, 31, 
    33, 28, 26, 31, 33, 27, 34, 26, 28, 27, 27, 30, 29, 31, 34, 
    30, 26, 31, 33, 33, 27, 30, 28, 32, 31, 29, 32, 31, 25, 28, 
    28, 26, 32, 29, 26, 31, 28, 29, 30, 25, 27, 32, 27, 28, 28, 
    30, 24, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 26, 28, 26, 26, 28, 31, 30, 27, 
    26, 28, 25, 24, 24, 30, 27, 26, 26, 27, 26, 26, 24, 26, 28, 
    25, 30, 26)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `V6-R0` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(30, 33, 33, 32, 29, 30, 32, 31, 32, 30, 33, 30, 
    32, 33, 33, 32, 29, 31, 32, 28, 31, 29, 36, 29, 30, 30, 33, 
    31, 33, 30, 34, 32, 29, 31, 28, 30, 30, 29, 34, 31, 32, 31, 
    30, 28, 32, 29, 29, 32, 29, 28, 29, 29, 32, 31, 27, 32, 29, 
    31, 29, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 30, 30, 30, 32, 29, 29, 
    30, 29, 29, 29, 28, 28, 29, 30, 29, 29, 29, 30, 28, 30, 30, 
    29, 29, 29)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R0-R4` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(31, 32, 32, 33, 32, 32, 33, 31, 34, 32, 33, 33, 
    32, 31, 33, 31, 32, 32, 32, 30, 32, 31, 34, 30, 31, 32, 34, 
    33, 34, 32, 36, 33, 32, 32, 31, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
    31, 30, 30, 31, 32, 32, 30, 30, 32, 31, 31, 32, 30, 32, 29, 
    32, 31, 30, 32, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 31, 30, 31, 32, 31, 31, 
    30, 30, 30, 31, 30, 30, 31, 30, 31, 30, 30, 30, 31, 32, 30, 
    31, 30, 30)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame"), `R4-R9` = structure(list(year = 2011:2100, 
    mean = c(27, 29, 28, 28, 27, 30, 29, 27, 30, 26, 30, 28, 
    29, 28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 25, 26, 26, 25, 27, 27, 27, 28, 30, 
    28, 29, 27, 29, 28, 29, 28, 26, 26, 28, 28, 30, 28, 27, 25, 
    26, 25, 25, 26, 26, 27, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 24, 27, 25, 
    28, 26, 24, 27, 26, 27, 25, 26, 26, 24, 26, 25, 26, 24, 25, 
    25, 26, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 25, 25, 25, 25, 26, 26, 
    26, 25, 24)), .Names = c("year", "mean"), row.names = c(NA, 
-90L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("EM-V6", "V6-R0", "R0-R4", 
"R4-R9"))), .Names = c("exp1.1", "exp1.2", "exp2.1", "exp2.2"
))
```

What I need to do is to "unlist" this nested list to a data frame that will look like this:

```
YEAR   EXP   EM-V6   V6-R0   R0-R4   R4-R9
2011  exp1.1  34      30      31      27
2011  exp1.2  34      30      31      27
2011  exp2.1  34      30      31      27
2011  exp1.1  34      30      31      27
```

Which means:

```
 - first year, first experiment, and growth stages.
 - first year, second experiment and growth stages.
 - first year, third experiment and growth stages
 - first year, fourth experiment and growth stages
 - second year, first experiment and growth stages
```

and so on.

How to perform that data transformation?

Comment: @akrun. Are you sure this question is a dupe? The other Q [How to reshape data from long to wide format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format) doesn't handle nested lists.

Comment: I agree, that other question addresses a completely different request. Please consider unmarking this question as duplicate @akrun.

Comment: @UweBlock It is already unduped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An alternative using `rbindlist` from the `data.table`-package twice:

```
library(data.table)
# bind the dataframes in the 'listed lists' together and include the year with the 'id'-parameter
# the resulting 'data.table's are returned as a list
step1 <- lapply(mylist, rbindlist, id = 'stages')
# bind the resulting list together and include the experiment id
step2 <- rbindlist(step1, id = 'experiment')
# reshape to wide format
dcast(step2, year + experiment ~ stages, value.var = 'mean')
```

Or in one go:

```
dcast(rbindlist(lapply(mylist, rbindlist, id = 'stages'), id = 'experiment'),
      year + experiment ~ stages, value.var = 'mean')
```

which gives:

```
     year experiment EM-V6 R0-R4 R4-R9 V6-R0
  1: 2011     exp1.1    34    31    27    30
  2: 2011     exp1.2    34    31    27    30
  3: 2011     exp2.1    34    31    27    30
  4: 2011     exp2.2    34    31    27    30
  5: 2012     exp1.1    34    32    29    33
 ---                                        
356: 2099     exp2.2    30    30    25    29
357: 2100     exp1.1    26    30    24    29
358: 2100     exp1.2    26    30    24    29
359: 2100     exp2.1    26    30    24    29
360: 2100     exp2.2    26    30    24    29
```

Comment: It works too, thanks a lot. I'm going to accept your answer because it uses a package that I was already loading in my code (no need to load extra packages).

Answer (score 7):

Alternate tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_df(mylist, ~bind_rows(., .id="id"), .id="EXP") %>% 
  spread(id, mean)
```

Comment: It also shows different & more succinct purrr syntax

Comment: And one uptick kinda means at least one person thought it was diff enough.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `tidyverse` with more compact and readable code

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
res1 <- mylist %>%
            #bind the inner datasets and create an id column
            map(bind_rows, .id = "id") %>%
            #bind the outer datasets and create an EXP column
            bind_rows(.id = "EXP") %>% 
            #reshape to wide format
            spread(id, mean) 

head(res1, 4)
#     EXP year EM-V6 R0-R4 R4-R9 V6-R0
#1 exp1.1 2011    34    31    27    30
#2 exp1.1 2012    34    32    29    33
#3 exp1.1 2013    32    32    28    33
#4 exp1.1 2014    28    33    28    32
```

---

Or we can approach this by looping through the `mylist` with `lapply`, then create a new column 'name' usign `Map` by `cbind`ing the `names` of the inner `list` elements, then `rbind` the `list` elements with `do.call(rbind`, now do a second `Map` to create a new column based on the `names` of 'mylist', `rbind` the `list` elements and then `reshape` from `base R` to convert it to 'wide'

```
res <- do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, lapply(mylist, function(x) 
    do.call(rbind, Map(cbind, x, name = names(x)))), EXP= names(mylist)))
res2 <- reshape(res, idvar = c("year", "EXP"), 
              timevar = "name", direction = "wide")
row.names(res2) <- NULL
head(res2, 4)
#   year    EXP mean.EM-V6 mean.V6-R0 mean.R0-R4 mean.R4-R9
#1 2011 exp1.1         34         30         31         27
#2 2012 exp1.1         34         33         32         29
#3 2013 exp1.1         32         33         32         28
#4 2014 exp1.1         28         32         33         28
```

NOTE: No external packages used (100% `base R`)

or use `dcast` from `reshape2` to transform to 'wide' format

```
library(reshape2)
res2 <- dcast(res, year + EXP~name, value.var = "mean") 
head(res2, 4)
#   year    EXP EM-V6 V6-R0 R0-R4 R4-R9
#1 2011 exp1.1    34    30    31    27
#2 2011 exp1.2    34    30    31    27
#3 2011 exp2.1    34    30    31    27
#4 2011 exp2.2    34    30    31    27
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! I'm glad I asked this question, because the answer was WELL beyond my R skills.

Comment: @thiagoveloso  I also updated with a solution where no external packages are used.